# Getting accurate date time 10 days ago

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get the exact time and date 10 days ago in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format using python, currently using this:

```
currentDT = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print(currentDT)
previousDT = currentDT - timedelta(days=10)
print(previousDT)
```

Which works... though it seems kind of messy. Is there an easier or cleaner way to do this using DateTime?

Comment: Why do you create a datetime object (`datetime.now()`), format to string and parse that string to datetime object again? You could just [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) seconds and microseconds with zero (`currentDT = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)`).

Comment: Think `datetime.now()` returns a naive datetime. This may be a problem with being exact for when daylight savings rolls around. Usually a good idea to always use UTC as in `datetime.utcnow()` and then convert the UTC to an aware time where you desire.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire: utcnow also returns naive datetime. But why use such an error-prone construct? datetime.now takes a tz argument which you can feed with timezone.utc for example...

Comment: @MrFuppes Yep you're right, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `strptime` and `strftime` to floor the timestamp to the minute, just use `replace`.

```
datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0) - timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! Didn't know you could explicitly set time periods with replace!